# Python: Combine Two Lists of Dictionaries on Common Value

Tags: python

I have two lists of dictionaries. I want the union based on

```
list_1 = ({'foo': 'bar', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'}, {'foo': 'bar2', 'ip': '2.3.4.5'})
list_2 = ({'foo': 'bar3', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'})

#calculated
list_3 should be: ({'foo': 'bar3', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'})
```

I'm trying:

```
tmplist = list(item['ip'] for item in list_1
                   if item['ip'] in list_2)
```

Edit: I have it with nested for loops. Is there a more pythonic way?

```
for item1 in list1:
        print(item1['ip_address'])
        for item2 in list2:
            if item1['ip_address'] == item2['ip_address']:
                print("Got a match: " + item1['foo'] + " == " +item2['foo'])
```

Comment: Your ```list_3``` and ```list_2``` are same

Comment: Could you rewrite the question? Example `I have x and y, and want to get z` ?

Comment: I have `list_1` and `list_2` and want python to calculate `list_3`. Yes I know they're the same. If there's a matching IP in both lists (only matching on the IP) then I want a list of those matches calculated as list_3. `list_3` is the one I'm trying to get to...

Comment: `list_1` and `list_2` are not `list` s in you question. `list_1` is a `tuple` and `list_2` is a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected value & format of your question(Hope it's OK). using below
method you can find common values between list of dictionaries.

```
list_1 = [{'foo': 'bar', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'}, {'foo': 'bar2', 'ip': '2.3.4.5'}]
list_2 = [{'foo': 'bar', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'}]

y0_tupleset = set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in list_1)
y1_tupleset = set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in list_2)
y_inter = y0_tupleset.intersection(y1_tupleset)
y_inter_dictlist = [dict(it) for it in list(y_inter)]
print(y_inter_dictlist)
```

Comment: I thought that was it, but that only works when `foo` is `bar` in both lists. What is `foo=bar` in `list_1` and `foo=bar3` in `list_2`?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant `list_1` and `list_2` in your questions to be... lists, right? (As you have them, `list_1` is a `tuple` and `list_2` is a `dict`.

If that is the case, then you have to use square brackets `[]` instead of parenthesis `()` when declaring your lists.

```
list_1 = [{'foo': 'bar', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'}, {'foo': 'bar2', 'ip': '2.3.4.5'}]
list_2 = [{'foo': 'bar3', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'}]
```

Ok, assuming that, you could have an implementation like this:

```
def matchings(iter1, iter2, selector):
    keys = {*map(selector, iter1)}
    return [*filter(lambda e: selector(e) in keys, iter2)]
```

And use it like this:

```
matchings(list_1, list_2, lambda e: e['ip'])
# [{'foo': 'bar3', 'ip': '1.2.3.4'}]
```